# JOpenDocument reading from .ods file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a .ods file from jopendocument. But when I am trying to access/print the value of a particular cell a blank output is displayed.My code is :

```
for(int nRowIndex = 0; nRowIndex < r; nRowIndex++)
{
int nColIndex = 0;
for( ;nColIndex < t; nColIndex++)
{
System.out.println(sheet.getCellAt(nColIndex, nRowIndex).toString());
}
}
```

This gets printed on console:

```
<table:table-cell xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getCellAt` returns an Object of type `Cell`, to get the contained value as text use

```
sheet.getCellAt(nColIndex, nRowIndex).getTextValue()
```